# Change <tr> background when child <td> contains "specific text" with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am basically wanting to change the background color of a `<tr>` based on the contents of one `<td class="status">` in the row.

I've tried this, amongst numerous other things

```
$('.status:contains("Complete")') .parent() .css('background', '#dff0d8');
```

The code below works fine on it's own to color the `<td>`

```
$('.status:contains("Complete")') .css('background', '#dff0d8');
```

But the .parent() is not working to color the row. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply `css` to siblings of `td` instead of `tr` and also use [andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andself/) if you want to include current td.

```
$('.status:contains("Complete")').siblings().andSelf().css('background', '#dff0d8');
```

If you are using jQuery 1.8 + then use andBack instead of andSelf.

> The andSelf function has been deprecated and is now an alias for
>   .addBack(), which should be used with jQuery 1.8 and later, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/andself/).

Comment: this worked in highlighting everything but the <td class="status"> cell.

Comment: Check the updated answer, you need andSelf for including current element(s)

Comment: The `andSelf` should be called after the `siblings`.

Comment: indeed andSelf should be after. working now. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the closest `tr` parent of your `td`:

```
$('.status:contains("Complete")').closest('tr').css('background', '#dff0d8');
```

Comment: i've tried this, but no luck. seems like the simplest way. i'm using 1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  $('.status:contains("Complete")') .closest('tr') .css('background', '#dff0d8');
```